# iRate library for prompting message after 5 days

Tags: ios, irate

I am using iRate library from Github [iRate library here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)

If I want to prompt the rate view after 5 days when the user clicks on "remind me later" or "No, thanks", how should I do that.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on the github link you provided

> `@property (nonatomic, assign) float remindPeriod;`
>   How long the app
>   should wait before reminding a user to rate after they select the
>   "remind me later" option (measured in days). A value of zero means the
>   app will remind the user next launch. Note that this value supersedes
>   the other criteria, so the app won't prompt for a rating during the
>   reminder period, even if a new version is released in the meantime.
>   This defaults to 1 day.

So just set this to 5. Please read the docs more carefully in the future.